# utilizing the existing jquery object rather than creating a new

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, allocation

```
source = $("div");
b = source.filter("div");

console.log (source==b);
```

Will return 'false'.

Is there a way to get it to not allocate a new jquery object but rather modify the contents of the existing one?

I have a scenario where other objects maintain a reference to the 'source' jquery object, and will want to check if its contents has changed.

If this is impossible, I'm wondering what is the best way to 'hook' the destruction and reallocation so that the other jquery objects can be told what the new replacement 'source' object is after the old one has been freed.

Wondering if there is a jquery extension for this...

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all jQuery methods that change the set of DOM elements return a new jQuery object - they don't modify the current jQuery object.  That's the way jQuery is architected for a variety of reasons.

It would be possible to take the elements from the new jQuery object and put them back into the old jQuery object and trigger a method on that object when you change the elements, thus maintaining the previous references and notifying them of a change, but you'd have to write code to do that.

For example, though this generally breaks the paradigm that jQuery is designed for and things like `.end()` will no longer work properly, you could create a new method for setting the contents of an existing jQuery object like this:

```
​jQuery.fn.set = function(elems) {
    this.length = elems.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        this[i] = elems[i];
    }
}​
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
var source = $("div");
var b = source.filter("div");
source.set(b);
```

If you want to create a notification of this change, you can use [jQuery custom events](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/) to monitor and notify of the change.  Or, you could just add a callback list to the jQuery object that would get called on that jQuery object by `.set()` anytime it makes a change.

Comment: for the 'not breaking' part, wouldn't 'add' method perhaps be better?

In any case I'm wondering if a more fundamental rewrite of the jquery methods might spare the allocation of a second object.  Though it might be out of my depth without a week or several of researching the jquery source code...

Comment: @RobF - `.add()` creates a new jQuery object.  That is not intuitive from the name and it fools me regularly, but it does create a new jQuery object - it does not add to the current one.

Comment: I'm wondering if a more compatible version of your method could be achieved with $.extend() ?  I can't find a similar method for the inverse though to empty out the object...

Comment: @RobF - the most compatible way of doing this would be to not maintain references to the original jQuery object.  Instead, maintain a reference to a holder of the jQuery object so then you can replace the jQuery object with a new one inside the holder and everyone will automatically see the new jQuery object.  Then, no jQuery changes need to be made and ALL compatibility is preserved.  The OP's code would have to be modified though to wrap the jQuery object in another object and remember the wrapper rather than the object itself.

Comment: One other thing (not sure if it justifies a new question): I notice there's a 'data' function for storing metadata for elements, but is there anything similar for storing data for jquery object itself?  I don't know if I want to be doing this.<name> in case of naming conflicts, so I'm wondering if there's a reserved space for it...

Comment: @RobF - A jQuery object is just a javascript object.  You can add your own custom property to any object to store your data there if need be.  Normally chaining in jQuery (which often creates a new jQuery object) will not preserve custom properties though.  `.data()` is used for associating data with a particular DOM element, not with a jQuery object.  Like I recommended in my previous post, if you have data to store, I'd suggest using your own wrapper object and storing your data and the jQuery object in your own wrapper object.  Then, you can use jQuery methods and not lose your own data.

Comment: I knew I could store things on the object but I was concerned about name-conflicts with existing jquery methods or possible yet-to-exist ones, hence I wondered if there was some standardised reserved 'namespace'-like member of the jquery objects.

Guess not. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to track events, bind variables to changes in source or other objects, etc., then I'd recommend looking into an MVC framework like backbone.js or knockout.js.

See also: [The Top 10 Javascript MVC Frameworks Reviewed](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/)

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants.  There is other code that has references to the original `source` jQuery object and the OP wants the filter operation to be applied to THAT object.  Your code does not do that.  Your code creates a new jQuery object and then assigns that to the variable `b`.  The original `source` jQuery object is unchanged so the other code that has a reference to it will not see any change.

Comment: What he said.  They are not equal in value, only their members are.  (This addresses a comment the OP edited away)

Comment: @jfriend: Right, got it. But the frameworks recommendations are still valid, so I've just deleted the first part.